# long long int on 32-bit Linux vs 64-bit Linux and MPFR

Tags: c++, gcc, mpfr

How exactly does a 32-bit Linux system handle `long long int` compared to 64-bit Linux?

On my 32 bit system I use a [C++ wrapper](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/) for the MPFR data type; this wrapper has a constructor defined for `long int` but not `long long int`. Nevertheless, on the 32-bit system this code just works:

```
long long int i=5LL;
mpreal myVar(i);
cout<< "this was constructed with a long long int:" <<myVar <<endl;
```

How is this possible? Does the 32-bit gcc just somehow cast the `long long int` into say `long int` for which the `mpreal` data type *does* have a constructor? If the above code is run on 64-bit Linux then the compiler results in an error about the construction being ambiguous.

I know that some people will tell me not to use `long long int` at all on 64 bit, but unfortunately, I'm using another library (odeint) where this is built in to the code to construct my given multiprecision data type this way, so I don't think I can change things.

Is `long long int` exactly the same as `long int` on 64-bit anyway? Will I lose data if I cast to `long int`? e.g. if I make my own constructor like:

```
mpreal(const long long int u, mp_prec_t prec, mp_rnd_t mode)
{
    mpfr_init2(mp,prec);
    mpfr_set_si(mp, u, mode);
}
```

Comment: Which constructors are ambiguous?

Comment: `error: call of overloaded 'mpreal(long long int)' is ambiguous`. It is simply not defined to be constructed from a `long long int`, but nevertheless on 32 bit gcc just works anyway, but not on 64 bit linux. Unless I write my own constructor for construction from `long long int` into the `mpreal.h`, as in my OP.

Comment: From wiki: `On 32-bit Linux, DOS, and Windows, int and long are 32-bits, while long long is 64-bits. On 64-bit Linux, int is 32-bits, while long and long long are 64-bit`. I think this may explain the situation, mpreal looks like it checks if 32 bit and if so defines a constructor for int64_t (which is long long int on 32x system). But for 64x system, `long int` and `long long int` are the same thing, so in principle no one should be feeding in `long long int` so I guess such a constructor was not defined?

Comment: Where exactly does the problem occur in odeint (file and linenumber)?

Comment: /odeint/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta_dopri5.hpp:300: error: call of overloaded 'mpreal(long long int)' is ambiguous

Comment: odeint/boost/numeric/odeint/stepper/runge_kutta_dopri5.hpp:301: error: call of overloaded 'mpreal(long long int)' is ambiguous

Comment: also same error at 302, 303

Comment: See my answer below also, and author of MPFRC++ at http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/#comment-7444. But would it be possible in odeint to to `use types with explicit number of bits:  int32_t, int64_t from stdint.h. Then move from x32 to x64 would be painless` as author of MPFRC++ suggests? Maybe this is a lot of work..I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the author of mpreal.h about this (the full answer is at http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/#comment-7444), firstly regarding building a new constructor for `long long int` on a 64x system:

```
>Functions “mpfr_set_ui/si” should be fine.
>Basically constructor for “long long int” should be equivalent to “long int” one.

>GNU GCC system makes porting from x32 to x64 a little bit messy. It automatically  
>upgrades integer types to x64 bits, which could easily break code being ported.

>The best workaround for GCC would be to use types with explicit number of bits:  
>int32_t, int64_t from stdint.h. Then move from x32 to x64 would be painless.

>However neither authors of MPFR nor developers of numeric libraries follow this    
>standard using “long long int”, “long int”, “intmax_t” all of which means different 
>things on x32 and x64 in GCC world.

>There is some macro-logic in mpreal.h which tries to make things smooth:
>(a) for x32 builds we define additional constructors for int64_t (aka “long long int” 
>or “intmax_t” ) 
>(b) for x64 builds we remove constructors for such type since “long int” is already 
>64bit wide.

>Macro MPREAL_HAVE_INT64_SUPPORT plays only “suggestive” role, it is undefined 
>automatically for x64 builds on GCC to avoid clash among integer types.

>The better way would be to detect bit resolution of all integer types at compile time  
>(using macros or meta-magic similar to boost) and add suitable routines to mpreal 
>class. This could easily grow to be more complex than mpreal itself :) .

>Maybe I will come up with better solution in future versions, any suggestions are 
>welcome.
```

So I think building in my constructor from the OP will fix things to work OK on a x64 system, but will need to be removed again if going back to x32 system otherwise it will cause a clash. The reason is that `MPREAL_HAVE_INT64_SUPPORT` macro gets defined on 32x and constructors for `int64_t` (aka `long long int` on 32x) get defined, so adding another such constructor will cause a clash; this is also the reason my code just worked out of the box on a 32 system. On a 64x system `MPREAL_HAVE_INT64_SUPPORT` macro is undefined and such constructors are removed since `long int` is already 64bit wide, so there was no need for the author to have a `long long int` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

- For sizes of various types check the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/standards), `long long` has to be represented with at least 64 bits.
- To see what the compiler really does with your code, you can use e.g. `objdump -D` on the binary (or the intermediate object file).
- On 32 bit arch you **will** lose data if you cast from `long long` to `long`.
- As far as I understand it, the compiler might have troubles deciding which constructor to use (basically can't decide whether to use `ctor(int)` or `ctor(long int)`).

**EDIT:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
uint64_t x = 5;
mpreal myVar(i);
```

works as the `c-tor(uint64_t)` is defined (or better said an unambiguous match can be found) - because on 64bit arch the `(unsigned) long int` is equivalent to `uint64_t` (for glibc it actually is defined as such). The error arises from the rules compiler uses when dealing with overloaded functions - for more information refer to the [C++11 standard](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard)/[draft](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard).

Generally speaking, if you want your code portable, you should use the types defined in [`inttypes.h` or `stdint.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h) - which is C99 - i.e. `uintXX_t` and `intXX_t`. These types are guaranteed to provide the exact width, see the wiki link above for more info.

Comment: I think on a 32x system, `MPREAL_HAVE_INT64_SUPPORT` gets defined (already as part of the mpreal.h) and in this case a constructor is present, that will take the 64 bit `long long int`. On the 64 bit system one would not normally use `long long int`, but rather just `long int` as both are 64 bits anyway, so in this case mpreal.h hasn't explicitly defined such a constructor. I added my own as shown in the OP, that is essentially the same as the `long int` constructor, and things compile. On 64x I don't think this cast from `long long int` to `long int` loses data.

Comment: Right, on 64bit `lli -> li` won't lose data (depends on the actual types widths, but I believe `li` is usually a quad-word on 64 bit archs).